# Node js - Socket.io-client is not works with remote socket.io server

Tags: node.js, sockets

When I test the socket.io and socket.io-client on localhost, both works well. 
But when I test on remote, (socket.io) on remote, and socket.io-client on localhost, it does not work.

```
// here is my snippet
 var io = require('socket.io-client'),
 socket = io.connect('52.74.209.168', { port: 80 });
 socket.on('connect', function(){
 console.log('connect');
 socket.emit('message', 'hi');
});
```

Comment: Please describe more about the situation that works and the situation that does not so we might understand more about the differences.

Comment: now i add http to the ip ,and it works ,thanyou!

Answer (score 0):

In your html code add socket.io.js script and write as it is mentioned below:

```
<head>
   <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
           var socket = io.connect("52.74.209.168:80");
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: well ,socket.io.js works well on browser,but now i had solve this problem ,just add http:// ahend 52.74.209.168:80,thankyou